# laravel ajax submitting schedule interview form error

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, datetime

I want to store schedule interview information using laravel and ajax. but I got an error.I use datetime for input type of schedule time.but I guess the mysql doesnt allow my datetime data that had sent by ajax.
please share your solution for solving this proble.

html code:

```
<form id="interview-form" class="form-horizontal" >
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row mt-4">
                                <label class="col-1 col-form-label" for="interview_time"> Time </label>
                                <div class="col-11">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" id="interview_time" name="interview_time" required="" value="{{old('interview_time') ?? today()}}"/>
                                    <div id="interview_time_error" class="text-danger"> </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div style="margin-left: 64px" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2"> Send Email </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-1 col-form-label" for="logo"></label>
                                <div class="col-11">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block rounded waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="save_interview"> Schedule &nbsp; <i class="mdi mdi-account-star"></i> </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Ajax code:

```
 $('body').on('click','#save_interview', function(){
                var url = "{{route('web.applicant.schedule_interview')}}";
                var applicant_id = localStorage.getItem("applicant_id");
                var interview_time = $('#interview_time').val();
                var link = $('#link').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                    method:"post",
                    data:{
                        applicant_id:applicant_id,
                        interview_time:interview_time,
                        link:link,
                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#interview-form")[0].reset();
                        $("#interview-modal").modal('hide');
                        toastr["success"]("Interview Scheduled Successfully..!");
                        $(".text-danger").html('');

                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        toastr["warning"]("Check The Fields Some Error Occurs!");
                        let errors = data.responseJSON.errors;
                        if(errors && "interview_time" in errors)
                        {
                            $("#interview_time_error").html(errors.name[0]);
                        }
                        if(errors && "link" in errors)
                        {
                            $("#link_error").html(errors.name[0]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Laravel Code:
I convert the datetime to this format for saving in mysql database.

```
public function schedule_interview(Request $request)
    {
        $time = Carbon::parse($request->get('interview_time'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        ApplicantInterview::create([
            'applicant_id' => $request->get('applicant_id') ,
            'interview_time' => $time ,
            'link' => $request->get('link') ,
            'status' => 'default' ,
        ]);
        return response()->json(["message" => "Interview scheduled successfully!"]);
    }
```

Comment: How does your date look like standard iso would always work as that is native to MySQL, so use that to store and to show your date you can format it